# how to retrieve record by Ajax and display in table Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
I want show the specific record by id through on click event in model
```

the model is papering without any detail fetched by url function

```
     <button id="{{$res->id}}" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-xl" onclick="viewslip(this.id)">View Slip</button>
```

I couldn't get any error so I could debug this.
here i am using ajx request for getting the data by onclick function through id
function viewslip(id){
$.ajax({

```
   url: "{{url('/view/payment/slip')}}"/+id,
   type: "GET",
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data){
    $('#fname').text(data.paymentslip.firstname); 
    $('#lname').text(data.paymentslip.lastname);        
          
   }
```

})
}

```
model where I am appending data

    <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                      <tr>
                        <th style="width:50%">First Name:</th>
                        <td><h1 id="fname"></h1></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th style="width:50%">last Name:</th>
                        <td><h1 id="lname"></h1></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>


        Method in Controller

         public function viewslip($id){         
         $paymentslip= Order::where('reservationid', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();   
         return response::json(array(
         
         'paymentslip'=>$paymentslip,
         
         ));        
            
        }
```

Comment: so what doesn't work ?

Comment: Thanks Swati for showing Interest for helping me .Actually there is no error is showing in console and I am not getting any result print in html table

Comment: First check `console.log(data)` is exist ?

Comment: Hello Noman . actually I think my onclick function is not executing .that's why I am not getting any data in Console .log (data).how to check onclick function aatch with button is working or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code

```
onclick="viewslip({{$res->id}})"
```

And in Your function use

```
function viewslip($orderId){

    var orderId = $orderId;
    $.ajax({

       url:"{{url('')}}/view/payment/slip/"+orderId,  // Your problem was here
       type: "GET",
       dataType:"json",
       success:function(data){
           $('#fname').text(data.paymentslip.firstname); 
           $('#lname').text(data.paymentslip.lastname);        
          
      }
})
```

Comment: how can I use $orderId there is I did use   onclick="viewslip({{$res->id}})"

Comment: Nothing happened Url or onclick is not working in my opinion

Comment: it's a variable name only. `viewslip(this.id)` == viewslip({{$res->id}}). Is it ??

Comment: Thanks Man. You made or save my day brother .your help is so much for me at this moment .Thanks from Heart :)